# MVC Intercept Button Click for Modal Dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a single MVC ASP.NET form with two buttons as such.

```
<button id="btnAcceptAll" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" name="button" value="accept"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Accept</button>
<button id="btnRejectAll" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" name="button" value="reject"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Reject</button>
```

And they get handled in my controller where I differentiate between the two buttons

```
[ActionName("Index")]
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult IndexPost(string button, QcMatchViewModel model)
{}
```

And this all works perfectly, but I am trying to an extra piece of logic, where when the user clicks the reject button I also get pop up a dialog window and when they fill this in and hit enter the button the submits the page as normal.

Was thinking something like this

```
$('#btnRejectAll').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
});
```

But then how do I get the button to submit as normal ?

Comment: add a button in dialog and programmatically submit form

Comment: Whats the Jquery for making it submit ?

Comment: ``$("#idofForm").submit()`` or ``$("#idofForm").trigger("submit")``

Comment: Ok but since I have two buttons as you can see in the OP will that still remember what original button i pressed on ?

Comment: you wan to click again that button from which dialog has opened???

Comment: No I want Reject Button - Dialog - Submit Dialog - In controller realise still I clicked Reject Button

Comment: Then you need the reject as a normal button that opens the dialog and in this dialog you can have your reject submit button

Comment: then in dialog button click you can do ``$("#btnRejectAll").click()`` to click it programmatically